# RESTful routing in Zend 1.x

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, phpunit

I am new to Zend Framework and am trying to implement a RESTful controller in Zend and trying to write unit tests for my controller. I am following the REST API available at: https://github.com/codeinchaos/restful-zend-framework but for every kind of test, PHPUnit always hits 404 (observable by asserting the response codes - the one I expect and the one that PHPUnit receives), thus failing the tests.

I have added all code in respective files as this REST API's readme instructs:

• I have added a module specific for REST: /application/modules/api.
• In my application.ini, I have the following:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "REST_"

rest.default = "xml"
rest.formats[] = "json"
rest.formats[] = "xml"

resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.class = "Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler"
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.module = "default"
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.controller = "error"
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.action = "error"

resources.router.routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route
```

• In my application/bootstrap.php:

```
public function _initREST()
{
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    // set custom request object
    $frontController->setRequest(new REST_Request);
    $frontController->setResponse(new REST_Response);
    $frontController->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules');

    // Add the REST route for the API module only
    $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController, array(), array('api'));
    $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
}
```

• In my /application/modules/api/Bootstrap.php:

```
public function _initREST()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        // Register the RestHandler plugin
        $frontController->registerPlugin(new REST_Controller_Plugin_RestHandler($frontController));

        // Add REST contextSwitch helper
        $contextSwitch = new REST_Controller_Action_Helper_ContextSwitch();
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($contextSwitch);

        // Add restContexts helper
        $restContexts = new REST_Controller_Action_Helper_RestContexts();
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($restContexts);
    }
```

• Out of my own experiments, I have also added a line $autoloader->registerNamespace('REST_') to my /public/index.php where $autoloader refers to an instance of Zend_Loader_Autoloader.

• My test's location: /tests/application/modules/api/controllers/RestClassTest.php
• This is my one of my tests for getAction():

```
public function testGetAction()
{
    $this->request->setMethod('GET');
    // Have tried other variations of URI too but all bear same result (getting 404) in tests indicating that routing is not set at the fundamental level. 
    $this->dispatch('/api/learn-to-rest?id=51fc287fc55ffc4006410bca');   

    $body = $this->getResponse()->getBody();
    $json = json_decode($body, true);
    $this->assertEquals('John Doe', $json['name']);    

    $httpResponse = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
    $this->assertEquals(200, $httpResponse);
}
```

• And this is my getAction():

```
public function getAction() 
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $objectId = $request->getParam('id'); 

    // Validation for ID
    $this->_validateMongoObjectIdAction($objectId);

    // Perform DB record selection
    $records = new Db_Collection_Class(new Db_Mongo_Class);
    $result = $records->findInCollection(array('_id' => new MongoId($objectId)));     
    if ($result === null) {
        // Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
    }

    // Dispatch records in JSON format
    $this->_helper->json($result);
}
```

It is true that I am setting a 404 for no-result-found situation but confining specifically at getAction, it is hitting 404 with test for a recognized valid ID as well.

I checked numerous resources (including the example provided by this API and Matthew O'Phinney's post: http://www.mwop.net/blog/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html) and all instruct to follow the same things that I am already doing. It is evident that I am missing something they are telling or am not comprehending some factor. I'll be obliged if anyone guides me where I'm doing what wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove:

```
$frontController->setRequest(new REST_Request);
```

in _initRest() ?

Comment: No, but it turned out that I don't need _/application/modules/api/Bootstrap.php_ that this REST API's readme instructs to have. Why the API author will have it is beyond me; anyone knows about it, please share.

Secondly, I figured that no matter what I do in tests or my code, nothing gets reflected anywhere. So some more digging regarding Zend resulted in knowledge that for a controller class in module directory, module name has to be prepended with the class name i.e. `class Api_RestClassController`. Now, at least PHPUnit is finding my code class.